# How to make maximize performance of Gstreamer

Tags: camera, streaming, wifi, gstreamer, microphone

I'm trying to stream video of camera and audio of mic using Gstreamer.
Use Odroid C1+ as a server and PC as a client.
When I use lan cable, it's perfact. But it's performance significantly decrease when I use WiFi.

I used

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=localhost port=5000 alsasrc device="hw:1,0" ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=localhost port=6000
$ gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=localhost port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! autovideosink sync=false tcpclientsrc host=localhost port=6000 ! gdpdepay ! autoaudiosink sync=false
```

and

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=localhost port=5000 sync=false alsasrc device='hw:0,0' ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=localhost port=6000 sync=false
$ gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=localhost port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false tcpclientsrc host=localhost port=6000 ! gdpdepay ! autoaudiosink sync=false
```

How can I maximize the performance of the streaming of Gstreamer,
and also synchronize video and audio?

**Update**

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! vaapih264enc ! rtph264pay ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=localhost port=5000
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVaapiEncodeH264:vaapiencodeh264-0: Could not initialize supporting library.
Additional debug info:
gstvideoencoder.c(1559): gst_video_encoder_change_state (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVaapiEncodeH264:vaapiencodeh264-0:
Failed to open encoder
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I ran this at Ubuntu16.04, VMware on i5-6400 CPU and no GPU PC for test.

Comment: The first pipe is more network demanding - because you send unencoded raw frames (which are big) .. the second pipe is more CPU demanding. You can chceck gst-omx, vaapi etc to use hw encoding for second pipe

Comment: What is the bellagio and generic at configureing omx?

Comment: I installed omx and vaapi both, but can use nothing haha..First when I command `gst-inspect-1.0 | grep omx`, nothing comes. And I'll update about error from running vaapi.

Comment: well I am not sure if you can use vaapi in vmware .. doing hw acceleration in virtualized OS is kind of .. well harder/ unstable / not working

Comment: you must test this at Odroid .. not in VMWare - the gst omx uses api OpenMax api which is not present on PC - it can by tried but its just for testing purposes..

Comment: Okay then, could you tell me how to install gst omx at Odroid?

Comment: I just found [this](http://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=2357) .. [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/528/how-can-i-install-gstreamer-gst-omx) is on raspbian.. maybe its similar - you have to read through that

Comment: Well I got a problem when I ran `./autogen.sh`. I have gstreamer1.0 but it says `configure: No package 'gstreamer-1.0' found \
configure: error: no gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.2.2 (GStreamer) found \
  configure failed`

Comment: you need to have correct path to sources of GStreamer core.. best to use pkg-config `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/user/gst/1.6/gstreamer/pkgconfig` (if I recall correctly) .. and maybe PATH, GST_PLUGIN_PATH and also maybe LD_LIBRARY_PATH .. but thats maybe too ugly - play with it a little :)

Comment: or if you have some gstreamer in system install the -dev versions

Comment: I installed gst-omx downloaded from [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-omx.html) and `./autogen.sh --with-omx-target=bellagio`, `make`, `make install`. But I can't find about it at `gst-inspect-1.0 | grep omx`

Comment: hmm, I read something about blacklisted plugins on the raspberry page I linked above.. why do you use bellagio? Check [this](https://github.com/01org/gst-omx/wiki) at bottom - about blacklisting

Comment: Ah,,,,,I tested with raspberrypi and it's performance is much better than odroid. It's smooth to install gstreamer in raspberry pi with `apt-get install gstreamer1.0`(included omx) and it shows perfect performance when use omx. And I still don't success install and use omx in odroid. I need to use it in odroid. I don't know what's the difference and problem.

Comment: Is the Odroid having OpenMax IL layer implemented/installed? what about the blacklisting, have you checked? I found [this](https://github.com/irtimmer/moonlight-embedded/issues/147) and [this](http://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=3259) .. search for more .. maybe ask on the forum of Odroid

Comment: I found that I don't have to use vaapi or omx. libav also good at encoding on odroid. So I'm testing what codec is best for streaming. Thanks for answering every foolish question.

Comment: its not foolish.. I am surprised that Odroid has little support in OpenMax.. its always good to use HW acceleration when possible, you will never achieve as good results with SW encoding